De Rham Cohomology of $M\times S^n$
I was recently asked to prove that $$H^k(M\times S^n)\cong H^k(M)\oplus H^{n-k}(M)$$ for all $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $M$ a compact $C^\infty$ manifold without boundary. At the time, we had nothing stronger than the Mayer-Vietoris sequence. I suspect that there is a nice way to solve this without the Kunneth formula or something along those lines, so I wanted to post it here to see if anyone can find such a solution.

This is a simple special case of the Künneth formula. But Mayer-Vietoris is the way to go. I don't know what you mean by "a very ad-hoc solution."

Let $H^*(M)$ denote the de Rham cohomology algebra of $M$. You could use the Leray-Hirsch theorem which in this case says that there is an isomorphism of $H^*(M)$-modules
$$H^*(M)\otimes H^*(S^n) \cong H^*(M\times S^n).$$
Here, the tensor product is graded. So, $H^k(M\times S^n) \cong \bigoplus_{p+q = k} H^p(M)\otimes H^q(S^n)$. However, $H^q(S^n)$ is nonzero only in degrees $0$ and $n$ and in those cases it is the ground field, $\Bbb{R}$. In particular,
$$H^k(M\times S^n) \cong H^{k-n}(M)\otimes H^n(S^n)\oplus H^k(M)\otimes H^0(S^n) = H^{k-n}(M)\oplus H^k(M)$$
for each $k\in \Bbb{Z}$.
